# Redirect/intercept function calls within a package function

Tags: r

Suppose I'm calling function PackageFuncA which exists within a 3rd party package (i.e. a library from CRAN).  PackageFuncA in turn calls PackageFuncB within the same 3rd party package.  Is there a way to call PackageFuncA such that when it calls PackageFuncB, it will in fact call my own implimentation of PackageFuncB?  In other words, can I intercept the call to PackageFuncB?

I think the solution involves creating my own PackageFuncB function and then calling PackageFuncA within the same environment and not the PackageFuncA's environment, but I couldn't get it to work with do.call nor eval.

Comment: Would it be easier to create your own PackageFunA and alter the call to PackageFunB so that it calls your function instead?

Comment: See `?assignInNamespace`

Comment: joran - I'd rather not maintain my own version of PackageFuncA, especially since its more than just a few lines of code.

Comment: Andrie - I actually want my version of PackageFuncB to be a wrapper around the 3rd party PackageFuncB.  So my func gets called first, I do some work, then pass on to the real PackageFuncB.  So I don't want to replace the existing function.

Comment: also I wouldn't want to affect the functionality of PackageFuncB in other parts of my code, just in one instance where I want to redirect the call

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a one-liner that does it.   Here `PackageFuncA` is `stats::acf` and `PackageFuncB` is `stats:::plot.acf` which we want to replace with `my.plot.acf` .   `my.plot.acf` prints `"Hello"` and then calls the real `stats:::plot.acf` .

```
# we want this to run in place of stats:::plot.acf
my.plot.acf <- function(x, ...) { cat("Hello\n"); stats:::plot.acf(x, ...) }

# this does it
library(proto)
acf <- with(proto(environment(acf), acf = stats::acf, plot.acf = my.plot.acf), acf)

# test
acf(1:10)
```

A proto object is an environment such that any function inserted into the object via the `proto` function has its environment automatically reset to that object.  The first arg of `proto()` is the parent of the proto object.

In the example above, its been set up so that the `acf` variable refers to the version of `acf` that was inserted into the proto object (which is the same as the original except its environment has been modified to be the proto object).  When the new `acf` function is run `plot.acf` is a free variable (i.e. not defined in `acf`) so it is looked up in `acf`'s  parent and that is the environment in the proto object where it finds the new `plot.acf`.  `acf` might have other free variables but in those cases as they are not found in the proto object it looks into the parent of the proto object which is the original environment of the original `acf`.  In terms of diagrams we have this where `<-` means left side is parent of right side:

```
environment(stats::acf) <- proto object <- revised acf
```

and the proto object contains both the `plot.acf` and the revised `acf` .

We have also set the environment of the new `plot.acf` to the proto object.  We may or may not have needed to do this.  In many cases it won't matter.   If it were important not to set the environment of the new `plot.acf` then it would be done like this because proto never sets the environment of functions inserted using `[[...]]` :

```
acf <- with(p <- proto(environment(acf), acf = stats::acf), acf)
p[["plot.acf"]] <- my.plot.acf
```

In this example, both approaches work.

It would be possible to do all this with plain environments at the expense of having to use several lines of code:

```
# create new environment whose parent is the original acf's parent
e <- new.env(parent = environment(stats::acf))

# the next statement is only need to overwrite any acf you already might have from
# trying other code.  If you were sure there was no revised acf already defined 
# then the next line could be omitted.  Its a bit safer to include it.
acf <- stats::acf

# This sets the environment of the new acf.  If there were no acf already here 
# then it would copy it from stats::acf .
environment(acf) <- e

# may or may not need next statement.  In this case it doesn't matter.
environment(my.plot.acf) <- e

e$plot.acf <- my.plot.acf

acf(1:10)
```

In this case we have not placed the revised `acf` in `e` as in the proto example but only set its parent.  In fact, placing the revised `acf` into `e` or the proto object is not strictly necessary but was only done in the proto case because proto has the side effect of resetting the environment and it was that side effect we were after.  On the other hand it is necessary to put the revised `plot.acf` in `e` or the proto object in order that it be encountered prior to the original one.

You might want to read this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229087107_Prototype-Based_Programming_in_Statistical_Computation) and, in particular, the section on Proxies starting page 21 since the technique shown here is an example of a proxy object.

Comment: works perfectly!  I'll have to stare at this a bit before I figure out why.  A brief walk-through of what's happening would be a huge help, if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new copy of `PackageFuncA`, reset its environment, and write your own version of PackageFuncB.

```
environment(PackageFuncA) <- globalenv()  # makes a new copy of PackageFuncA

PackageFuncB <- function(...) ....   # will be called from your new PackageFuncA
```

You might have to do a bit of editing if `PackageFuncA` uses un-exported functions from its original package. Also, if you don't want the new `PackageFuncB` to be used elsewhere, you can wrap it inside your new `PackageFuncA` instead of placing it in the global environment.