# Editing stargazer source code -- saved edits don't render to pdf

Tags: r, stargazer

So I'm also preparing a table or regression results in stargazer, and I'm only showing the t-scores in the table from 10 different models side by side.  I have the same question as in this earlier post on [how to remove the "t = " from the stargazer results output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995868/r-stargazer-package-eliminate-t-label-from-reported-test-statistics) from @deca.

I've followed the answer given by @JNWHH, which is:

> 1. Access the edit-screen of the stargazer function with `trace(stargazer:::.stargazer.wrap, edit = T)`
> 2. Go to line 7103/7104 (may be different depending on your stargazer version) and look for .format.t.stats.left <- "t = " and .format.t.stats.right <- "" and edit it to your liking, e.g., .format.t.stats.left <- "[" and .format.t.stats.right <- "]"
> 3. Confirm with "save".

After completing these three steps and then calling the stargazer function again, I can see in the LaTeX code produced for my table that all of the "t = " have been removed.  However, when I knit the document, the resulting PDF still has the "t = " in them.

I wasn't sure what/if code was needed here for people to diagnose, but if so, please let me know and I can try to include what I'm running.  But really, I'm just following the three steps above exactly as described.  I have **not** restarted my R-session since editing the source code, so I don't think the problem stems from that.  If I'm missing something obvious, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

I gone through the solution. You have to adjust the `stargazer` source code while knitting the document. This is true for either text in html or latex in PDF output.

````
---
title: "stargazer_edits"
author: "Me"
date: "2023-01-13"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

## stargazer source edited

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(stargazer)

# I do this once
trace(stargazer:::.stargazer.wrap, edit = T)

model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=mtcars)

stargazer(model, type = "text", report = "vc*t")
```
````

While producing the document this opens the source code.

[image]

You can more easily find the part `.format.t.stats.left` (lines 7105 and 7106 at 13.01.2023) by searching the text file. You modify the style, e.g. change it to square brackets.

[image]