# Stargazer in R reporting t-value in addition to standard error and estimates

Tags: r, stargazer

I would like to add the t-value underneath the standard error in square bracket, how can I accomplish this with Stargazer?

```
school.reg1 <- lm(math~income+students+english, data=CASchools)
school.reg2 <- lm(read~income+students+english, data=CASchools)

stargazer(school.reg1, school.reg2,  type="latex",
          covariate.labels = c("Number of Students at School", "Median Income of Parents", "% of Non-Native English Speakers", "Total School Spending", "Percent Qualifying for CalWorks "),
          dep.var.labels = c("Math", "Reading"),
         keep.stat=c("n", "adj.rsq"),
         add.lines = list(c("AIC", round(AIC(school.reg1),2), round(AIC(school.reg2),2) )) )
```

Currently the table looks like this

[image]

Source code taken from https://bookdown.org/ejvanholm/WorkingWithData/attractive-output.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are also fine with "t=" instead of square brakets. Use the `report` option.

```
library(AER)
data("CASchools")

school.reg1 <- lm(math~income+students+english, data=CASchools)
school.reg2 <- lm(read~income+students+english, data=CASchools)

library(stargazer)
stargazer(school.reg1, school.reg2,  type="text",
          covariate.labels = c("Number of Students at School", "Median Income of Parents", "% of Non-Native English Speakers", "Total School Spending", "Percent Qualifying for CalWorks "),
          dep.var.labels = c("Math", "Reading"),
          keep.stat=c("n", "adj.rsq"),
          report = "vc*st",
          add.lines = list(c("AIC", round(AIC(school.reg1),2), round(AIC(school.reg2),2) )) )

 =============================================================
                                     Dependent variable:     
                                 ----------------------------
                                      Math         Reading   
                                      (1)            (2)     
-------------------------------------------------------------
Number of Students at School        1.498***      1.501***   
                                    (0.083)        (0.074)   
                                   t = 18.137    t = 20.177  
                                                             
Median Income of Parents             0.0001        -0.0001   
                                    (0.0002)      (0.0001)   
                                   t = 0.408     t = -0.739  
                                                             
% of Non-Native English Speakers   -0.406***      -0.569***  
                                    (0.035)        (0.031)   
                                  t = -11.632    t = -18.101 
                                                             
Total School Spending              636.628***    641.224***  
                                    (1.590)        (1.431)   
                                  t = 400.498    t = 448.017 
                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                                  3248.6        3160.46   
Observations                          420            420     
Adjusted R2                          0.625          0.735    
=============================================================
Note:                             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

To add those in square brackets, follow this approach and modify the source code of `stargazer` [R stargazer package: eliminate "t =" label from reported test statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995868/r-stargazer-package-eliminate-t-label-from-reported-test-statistics)