How to use ritest with multiple treatment arms
I would like to conduct randomisation inference test for three treatment arms and obtain the p-value for each treatment arm. I have a cluster and a strata variable which need to be part of the test. The package which I use is ritest.
I am unsure how to use ritest in this case as I have to perform the test on each treatment arm separately. I don't seem to be using the right resampvar in the ritest function. The resampvar should be the treatment arm for which I want the p-value, but I have an error when I use the coefficient name of the given treatment arm when I run the regression model before the ritest.
This is an illustration of what I am trying to do.


### Data
set.seed(123)

ngroup = 4

nrep = 15

treat <- rep(c("control", "treat1", "treat2", "treat3"), each = nrep)

strata <- sample(1:3, 60, replace =TRUE)

cluster <- sample(1:5, 60, replace =TRUE)

                 
Y<- rbinom(60, 1, 0.5)
                 
data <- cbind(Y, treat, strata, cluster)

data <- as.data.frame(data)

data <- data %>%
mutate(treat = as.factor(treat),
       Y = as.numeric (Y))


### Regression

#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_github("grantmcdermott/ritest")
library(ritest)

reg <- glm(Y ~ factor(treat) + factor(strata), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)

## I would like to have clusterred std. errors for the logit model and later on for the ritest.
### obtain clusterred se (source: https://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2014/10/easy-clustered-standard-errors-in-r.html)
get_CL_vcov<-function(model, cluster){
  require(sandwich, quietly = TRUE)
  require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
  
  M <- length(unique(cluster))
  N <- length(cluster)
  K <- model$rank
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
  
  uj  <- apply(estfun(model),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum))
  
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(model, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
  return(vcovCL)
}


vcovCL <- get_CL_vcov(reg, data$cluster)

clse <- sqrt(diag(vcovCL))

reg_ri = ritest(reg, resampvar = "treattreat1", cluster='cluster', strata='strata', reps=500, seed = 123, verbose = TRUE)

# treattreat1 I find as the coeff. name stored in the reg output for treat1 (the first tretament arm). 

I would appreciate any hints on what goes wrong with the ritest in this case. Or maybe I could use another R package for this?

Please [edit] your post to add the error message and identify the line causing the issue. Per when I run the regression model before the ritest ... is it the glm line? If so, I get no error.

I would start by not using factor(treat) and factor(strata) in the model formula, but define these beforehand. If I do that, I can run ritest(reg, resampvar = 'treattreat1') successfully, but defining strata doesn't work. However, ?ritest says: "Present limitations include: only 'lm' and 'fixest::feols' model objects are supported", so it appears glm models are not supported. I am not sure why you included the get_CL_vcov bit, since it doesn't appear to be related to your question?

I think that I found how to perform ritest with multiple treatment arms including strata and cluster. I think the problem with my data set-up from above was that I had the strata variable as a factor variable. The reason for this was that I have to include strata dummies in my regression and this appeared as a possible way to do this. However, the factor format of the strata variable confuses ritest when strata is specified. So, what I did is to format the strata variable as numeric, generate separate strata dummies to be used in the regression and then the ritest could be performed with strata variable. The cluster variable I have also as numeric, but I think this is standard format in datasets. For strata, I am not sure what is the common practice.
Here is all my code including exporting the results in stargazer. I export the marginal effects of the logit as they could be easily interpretable and the p-values form the test to compare the significance of the marginal effects and the ritest.
### Data
set.seed(123)

ngroup = 4

nrep = 15

treat <- rep(c("control", "treat1", "treat2", "treat3"), each = nrep)

#treat <- rbinom(60, 1, 0.5)

strata <- sample(1:3, 60, replace =TRUE)

cluster <- sample(1:5, 60, replace =TRUE)

Y<- rbinom(60, 1, 0.5)
                 
data <- cbind(Y, treat, strata, cluster)

data <- as.data.frame(data)

data <- data %>%
mutate(treat = as.factor(treat),
    strata = as.numeric(strata),
  cluster = as.numeric(cluster),
       Y = as.numeric (Y))

data <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(data, select_columns = "strata")

strata_vars <- c("strata_2", "strata_3")

### Logit with strata as numeric variable
reg1<- glm(as.formula(paste("Y ~ treat +", paste(strata_vars, collapse = "+"))), family = binomial(link = "logit"),  data = data)



## Conduct the ritest
resamp_vars <- c("treattreat1", "treattreat2", "treattreat3")  # Add more as needed

# Initialize a list to store results
p_values <- numeric(length(resamp_vars))
names(p_values) <- resamp_vars

for (resamp_var in resamp_vars) {
  # Perform the ritest for each resampling variable
  reg_ri_result <- ritest(reg1, resampvar = resamp_var, cluster = "cluster", strata = "strata", reps = 1000, verbose = TRUE)
  
  # Extract the p-value for each treatment arm
  p_value <- reg_ri_result$pval
  
  # Store each p-value in a vector (num format)
  p_values[resamp_var] <- p_value
}


### My reporting of the results with stargazer (marginal effects of the logit model with clustered std.errors + p.values of the ritest)

library(mfx)

regmfx <- logitmfx(Y ~ treat+ strata_2 + strata_3, clustervar1= "cluster", atmean = T, data=data)

p_mxf <- regmfx$mfxest[, 4] 

coeff_mfx <- regmfx$mfxest[,1]



library(stargazer)

stargazer(regmfx$fit, coef = list(coeff_mfx), se=list(p_mxf), p= list(p_values), report=('vcs*p*'), omit = c("strata_2", "strata_3", "Constant"), omit.stat = c("ll", "adj.rsq", "f", "ser", "aic"))

# to replace the p= and set it to [..], check this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995868/r-stargazer-package-eliminate-t-label-from-reported-test-statistics][1]

Maybe there is an easier and more elegant way to do this, but this I with what I managed to come up at this stage.
