# Using a gtable object with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm producing a gif with `gganimate`, and I'd like to make some tweaks to the plot format that can only be accomplished by converting a `ggplot` object to a `gtable`. For instance, I'd like to change the position of the plot title so that it always appears in the far left corner of the plot.

Here's an example of what the plot tweak would look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)

# Helper function to position plot title all the way to left of plot
align_titles_left <- function(p, newpage = TRUE) {
  p_built <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_build(p))
  gt <- invisible(ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(p_built))
  
  gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(gt$layout$r))
  gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "subtitle"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(gt$layout$r))
  
  
  # Prints the plot to the current graphical device
  # and invisibly return the object
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(gt, newpage = newpage)
  invisible(gt)
}

# Create an example plot
static_plot <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
             color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This title should appear in the far left.")

# Print the static plot using the adjustment function
align_titles_left(static_plot)
```

[image]

## How can I use this function with `gganimate`?

Here's some example `gganimate` code to turn the plot in this example into an animation.

```
# Produce the animated plot
static_plot +
  transition_states(Species,
                    transition_length = 3,
                    state_length = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the result. Explanation below:

[image: animated plot]

Any hacking with grobs should done ***after*** the individual frames of the animated plot have been created, but before they get drawn on the relevant graphics device. This window occurs in the `plot_frame` function of [`gganimate:::Scene`](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/blob/c5fc244385b532fe03818e3509db9aadedea92ad/R/scene.R).

We can define our own version of `Scene` that inherits from the original, but uses a modified `plot_frame` function with the grob hack lines inserted:

```
Scene2 <- ggproto(
  "Scene2",
  gganimate:::Scene,
  plot_frame = function(self, plot, i, newpage = is.null(vp), 
                        vp = NULL, widths = NULL, heights = NULL, ...) {
    plot <- self$get_frame(plot, i)
    plot <- ggplot_gtable(plot)

    # insert changes here
    plot$layout[which(plot$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(plot$layout$r))
    plot$layout[which(plot$layout$name == "subtitle"), c("l", "r")] <- c(2, max(plot$layout$r))

    if (!is.null(widths)) plot$widths <- widths
    if (!is.null(heights)) plot$heights <- heights
    if (newpage) grid::grid.newpage()
    grDevices::recordGraphics(
      requireNamespace("gganimate", quietly = TRUE),
      list(),
      getNamespace("gganimate")
    )
    if (is.null(vp)) {
      grid::grid.draw(plot)
    } else {
      if (is.character(vp)) seekViewport(vp)
      else pushViewport(vp)
      grid::grid.draw(plot)
      upViewport()
    }
    invisible(NULL)
  })
```

Thereafter, we have to replace `Scene` with our version `Scene2` in the animation process. I've listed two approaches below:

1. Define a separate animation function, `animate2`, plus intermediate functions as required to use `Scene2` instead of `Scene`. This is safer, in my opinion, as it doesn't change anything in the `gganimate` package. However, it does involve more code, & could potentially break in the future if the function definitions change at the source.
2. Over-write existing functions in the `gganimate` package **for this session** (based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24332249/8449629)). This requires manual effort each session, but the actual code changes required are very small, & probably won't break as easily. However, it also carries the risk of confusing the user, since the same function could lead to different results, depending on whether it's called before or after the change.

## Approach 1

Define functions:

```
library(magrittr)

create_scene2 <- function(transition, view, shadow, ease, transmuters, nframes) {
  if (is.null(nframes)) nframes <- 100
  ggproto(NULL, Scene2, transition = transition, 
          view = view, shadow = shadow, ease = ease, 
          transmuters = transmuters, nframes = nframes)
}

ggplot_build2 <- gganimate:::ggplot_build.gganim
body(ggplot_build2) <- body(ggplot_build2) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  inset2(4,
         quote(scene <- create_scene2(plot$transition, plot$view, plot$shadow, 
                                      plot$ease, plot$transmuters, plot$nframes))) %>%
  as.call()

prerender2 <- gganimate:::prerender
body(prerender2) <- body(prerender2) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  inset2(3,
         quote(ggplot_build2(plot))) %>%
  as.call()

animate2 <- gganimate:::animate.gganim
body(animate2) <- body(animate2) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  inset2(7,
         quote(plot <- prerender2(plot, nframes_total))) %>%
  as.call()
```

Usage:

```
animate2(static_plot +
           transition_states(Species,
                             transition_length = 3,
                             state_length = 1))
```

## Approach 2

Run `trace(gganimate:::create_scene, edit=TRUE)` in console, & change `Scene` to `Scene2` in the popup edit window.

Usage:

```
animate(static_plot +
          transition_states(Species,
                            transition_length = 3,
                            state_length = 1))
```

(Results from both approaches are the same.)

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you very much for your comments about the pros/cons of the two approaches. It seems like Approach 1 is the safest, and it could be implemented by stowing that code in a helper script (e.g. "Custom_Animation_Functions.R") and sourcing it from a main script (e.g. "Produce_Animated_Plots.R").