# Adding and Editing Functions of R-package

Tags: r, package, edit

**Goal:** I downloaded an R-package "ABC" from CRAN and would like to achieve two things:

1. edit an existing function `ex_fct` of that R-package.
2. add a new function `nw_fct` to that R-package.

and these adjustments shall be permanent.

**Situation:** There are good sources that explain the first aspect on how to edit/change/overwrite an *existing* function of an R-package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331690/modify-package-function), but trying to follow this approach seems not to work for adding *new* functions to a package.

**Question**: Hence, I wish to add the function `nw_fct` as a hidden function in that package so that it can be called via `ABC:::nw_fct`. How can this be done? Is there a way to simultaneously address both aspects?

Comment: You'll have to edit the source code for the package and then rebuild from source

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: ...but really you shouldn't mess with other people's packages unless you're making a PR. A better option is to make your own local package that depends on theirs as necessary.

Comment: Can't you just create your own package that has `Depends: ABC` in its `DESCRIPTION` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: The following steps worked for me (on a Mac) to simultaneously solve both aspects:

1. I downloaded package ABC as a tar file from the CRAN repository (file: "ABC_1.1-2.tar"). After opening the file by decompressing it via double-click, it shows the typical structure of Packages (metadata, vignettes, namespace, etc.) as described in the link provided by alistaire (see [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz) - very helpful, many thanks).
2. All the relevant files with the different algorithms (e.g. files "algo-A.R", "algo-B.R") are contained in the "R"-folder and inside the file "algo-A.R", I found the function `ex_fct`. I opened this file in R-Studio adjusted the `ex_fct` function as desired and added the `nw_fct` also to that file (because the `ex_fct` and `nw_fct` functions are related) and saved it under the same name, i.e. as "algo-A.R". As a result, I now have an updated package folder that contains my updated version of the "algo-A.R" file.
3. Finally, I used the `build` function of the `devtools` package to create a single bundled ".tar" file (say file "ABC_new.tar") from this updated package folder. Specifically, one may simply use: `build(pkg= "path1/ABC_1.1-2", path= "~path2/ABC_new.tar", manual=F, binary=F)`, where `path1` navigates to the place of the updated package folder and `path2` says where the bundled package shall be stored. *Notice: As I did this on a new machine, this step did not work immediately but required to first install e.g. TeXLive, Java Applications as well as several packages required by the ABC package (simply follow R's error commands).*
4. Finally, I was able to (permanently) install the updated package archive file in RStudio via: `install.packages(“~path2/ABC_new.tar", repos = NULL, type=“source”)`

Should you wish to undo these changes and have the original package again, you may simply remove the package and re-install the original one from CRAN.

Comment: Can you also explain how do you export the `nw_fct`?