# How to set time out in multidplyr

Tags: r, multidplyr, callr

I inconsistently get following error when using `multidplyr` (ie, for the same data sometimes I get the error, sometimes not):

> Error in rs_init(self, private, super, options, wait, wait_timeout) :
> Could not start R session, timed out

My setting looks like:

```
list1 <- list() 

for (i in 1:500){
  while(TRUE){
    test1 <- try(df %>% 
                   group_by(id) %>% 
                   recursive_func_c())
    if(!is(test1, 'try-error')) break
  }
  list1[[i]] <- test1
}
```

Where `recursive_func_c` is a function that calls:

```
cluster <- multidplyr::new_cluster(7)
```

As far as I understand it correctly, a multidplyr cluster consists of multiple R processes created by `callr`. It seems the error message I get comes from the `callr` package.
For debugging, I would like to set a longer time out time for `callr` within `multidplyr`. Is that possible?
Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this issue was solved here: https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr/issues/97

15 seconds is propably too short for my setting.

If you face the same issue, you can try to temporarily change `wait_timeout` of `new_cluster()` with `trace(new_cluster, edit=TRUE)` (more regarding general function modification can be found here: [Modify package function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331690/modify-package-function))

60 seconds seems to work for me.